# PostgreSQL regex check start with Latin and alpha character

Tags: regex, latin

I have to check String start with an alpha in PostgreSQL. I used this:

```
    SELECT string ~ '^([a-z]|[A-Z])'
```

But it doesn't work with strings start with a Latin character. For ex: ücp.

In Java, I use this regex:

```
    ^([\pL]).*
```

I tried it with PostgreSQL but it does not work as expected.

How can I write this regex in PostgreSQL?

Comment: What if you use `^[[:alpha:]]`?

Comment: Thank you! I works like a charm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The POSIX character class `[:alpha:]` is locale-dependent and matches Unicode letters as well.

Use

```
^[[:alpha:]]
```

See what the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-BRACKET-EXPRESSIONS) say:

> Standard character class names are: alnum, alpha, blank, cntrl, digit, graph, lower, print, punct, space, upper, xdigit. These stand for the character classes defined in ctype. A locale can provide others.